# How to build Xerces-c library for use with Embarcadero Technologies C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder, xerces-c, c++builder-10-seattle

I downloaded the Xerces-c source from the xerces.appache mirror. I want to create a DLL I can use with C++Builder 10.0 Seattle, for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

The build instructions and download archive provide a Visual C++ Solution I can use with VS Studio Express 2015, OR instructions to build with make files designed for Borland C++. Borland gave up the C++ tools a decade ago, so without even trying the make files, I assumed they would not work with my Embarcadero 10.0 Seattle compiler. Thus, I built xerces-all with VS Studio Express 2015, and it all appears to work. (The DLL built without error, and the samples built and seem to run.)

I have been trying to make changes to the VS Studio solution (changing calling convention from `__cdecl` to `__stdcall`), but that just makes the samples fail to build.

Following advice from Remy Lebeau and this article I found ([Using Visual C++ DLLs with C++Builder](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0012/Using_Visual_C_DLLs_with_CBuilder.htm)), I have attempted to use Embarcadero utilities TDUMP, IMPDEF and IMPLIB to extract the export names from the built DLL. These yield output that looks like this:

```
EXPORT ord:1763='?Initialize@XMLPlatformUtils@xercesc_3_1@@SAXKKKQBD0QAVPanicHandler@2@QAVMemoryManager@2@@Z'
```

I posted the application code I'm trying to build as a simple test in this thread:

[unresolved external 'xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize' in C++ Builder test app](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/38960564/)

I am confused beyond belief. How can I get *either* a DLL *or* a LIB I can use with my tools?

Comment: C++Builder still includes the old Borland compiler, so you should be able to use makefiles. And you don't need to change calling conventions in the code, `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` are standard conventions that C++Builder and VS support equally, the only difference is in the name mangling, and a DEF file can handle that.  If you are having problems using TDUMP, IMPDEF, and IMPLIB, you should post a separate question about that issue.

Comment: I know for a fact that Xerces works with older versions of C++Builder, so it should be possible to make it work in 10.0 Seattle as well.  Or, you could consider switching to a different XML library.  I personally use [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org) in C++Builder and it works fine for me.

Comment: I will post separate questions about my problems with TDUMP, IMPDEF and IMPLIB. I will also see if switching to libxml2 will make this all less painful. Thanks, Remy. You're always the one with the answers that help me.

Comment: I have now used the Xerces-provided MAKE files to create Xerces-bor_3_1_4.dll (for Win32) which works with my CX10 GUI. Sorry for assuming otherwise and starting this misleading thread.